# How to drag and drop panelbars in kendo ui?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

In my project i have a requirement to drag and drop the panel-bars with chart, Is it possible to drag and drop? if possible can any one provide examples in kendo ui please

Comment: Need to provide more information. From where to where? What did you try so far?

Comment: In my application 10 panel-bars are placed,need to change one panel-bar place to another panel-bar place.like below example  http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/drag-drop-panels/  this functionality need in kendo-ui?

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/364/ for my requriment,can you please provide  example here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Kendo UI Widget (not-official) that would simplify your development.

If you have your panel content defined as:

```
<div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel">
        <ul id="panelbar0" class="ob-panel-bar">
            <li class="k-state-active">
                <span class="k-link k-state-selected">Graph #0</span>
                <div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="panelbar1" class="ob-panel-bar">
            <li class="k-state-active">
                <span class="k-link k-state-selected"> Graph #1</span>
                <div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="panelbar2" class="ob-panel-bar">
            <li class="k-state-active">
                <span class="k-link k-state-selected"> Graph #2</span>
                <div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div></div>
        </ul>
        <ul id="panelbar3" class="ob-panel-bar">
            <li class="k-state-active">
                <span class="k-link k-state-selected"> Graph #3</span>
                <div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="panelbar4" class="ob-panel-bar">
            <li class="k-state-active">
                <span class="k-link k-state-selected"> Graph #4</span>
                <div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="panelbar5" class="ob-panel-bar">
            <li class="k-state-active">
                <span class="k-link k-state-selected"> Graph #5</span>
                <div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div><div>Hello, world!</div></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following JavaScript for initializing the panels:

```
$("#panelbar0").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "multiple"
});
$("#panelbar1").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "multiple"
});
$("#panelbar2").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "multiple"
});
$("#panelbar3").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "multiple"
});
$("#panelbar4").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "multiple"
});
$("#panelbar5").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "multiple"
});
```

You just need to add:

```
$(".panel-container").kendoOBSortableGrid({
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone().addClass("ob-being-dragged");
    }
});
```

See a demo in here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/WxUUL/

Comment: You are welcome!. Next release of `kendoOBSortableGrid` is coming soon with _smarter_ insertion.